# Switching PHP version PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2

Tags: 16.04, php, php7

i have installed 2 php versions on my PC here, i run this command

```
composer require kreait/firebase-php ^4.18
```

but that show error message :

**[InvalidArgumentException]

  Package kreait/firebase-php at version ^4.18 has a PHP requirement incompat

  ible with your PHP version (5.6.20)**

when i run phpinfo it's said php7.2 but when i check php -v it said php5.6
[image: screenshot]
anyone can help me out and why it's happen ?

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep php` will show all your installed PHP packages; remove those that pertain to the PHP version you don't want.

Comment: in this case sometimes i need php 5.6 too ... so i want it can be switching ...

Comment: Then you'll need to be a lot more specific about what you want to achieve. What exactly do you mean by "switching"?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

by adding this code in my composer.json :

```
"config": {

    "platform": {

        "php": "7.2.17"

    }

}
```